# YouTube player implementation

Tags: android, youtube-api

```
     package com.example.stm;
        
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        
        import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
        import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
        import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
        
        public class Youtube extends AppCompatActivity {
        
            YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
            String adres = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8QppD8yqdc";
            String toster = "Initialization failed";
            String apikey = "API_KEY";
        
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);
        
                youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
                YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener listener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(adres);
                        youTubePlayer.play();
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toster, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
                    }
        
                };
                youTubePlayerView.initialize(apikey, listener);
        
        
            }
        
        }

    
    
    
   

 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Hello guys! I`m trying to build in youtube player in my app. This is my code. When i press button to start activity, it starts, but then stops and returns back to parent activity. Please help to find out what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: you should to be add logcat for better understanding for others

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Menifest

```
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
             -------------
             Other stuff
             -------------
    </application>
```

Comment: i have it in manifest